# Is it possible to send POST data to another php in ajax?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I've built a search form and I've tried to send `$_POST` data to another php in ajax but it does not work.

And I want to know, Is it possible if I want to send `$_POST` data to `url:"searchby.php"` in ajax?

**search.php :**

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post" id="searchTerm">
   <input type="text" name="search" id="search" autocomplete="off">
   <button type="loading" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajax_arry=[];
    var ajax_index =0;
    var sctp = 100;

    $(function(){
        $('#loading').show();
        $.ajax({
            url:"searchby.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:"actionfunction=showData&page=1",
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('#demoajax').html(response);
            }
        });

        $(window).scroll(function(){

            var height = $('#demoajax').height();
            var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();
            if(ajax_arry.length>0){
                $('#loading').hide();
                for(var i=0;i<ajax_arry.length;i++){
                    ajax_arry[i].abort();
                }
            }
            var page = $('#demoajax').find('.nextpage').val();
            var isload = $('#demoajax').find('.isload').val();
            var searchTerm = "<?php echo $x; ?>";

            if ((($(window).scrollTop()+document.body.clientHeight)==$(window).height()) && isload=='true'){
                $('#loading').show();
                var ajaxreq = $.ajax({
                    url:"searchby.php",
                    type:"POST",
                    data:"actionfunction=showData&page="+page,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(response){
                        $('#demoajax').find('.nextpage').remove();
                        $('#demoajax').find('.isload').remove();
                        $('#loading').hide();
                        $('#demoajax').append(response);
                    }
                });
                ajax_arry[ajax_index++]= ajaxreq;
            }
            return false;
            if($(window).scrollTop() == $(window).height()) {
             alert("bottom!");
         }
     });
});

</script>
```

And my `searchby.php` should look like this.

**searchby.php :**

```
$searchstring = $_POST['search'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE p_name LIKE '%$searchstring %'";
```

Comment: are u getting any error in this code??

Comment: It doesn't send post value to searchby.php. I've check by echo $_POST['search'];. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You're trying to get `$_POST['search']` when i can't see you pass any parameter with this name.

Comment: yes @ZakariaAcharki: is right, and one more thing what is this??? var searchTerm = "<?php echo $x; ?>";   r u define anywhere this variable in PHP???

Comment: That's problem I don't know how to pass any parameter (Really sorry I'm just a beginner). That's all on my code that I've done.

Comment: Okay @VintageBeef you can use `.val()` check my answer.

Comment: do u want like that, if button submit search the result???

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki: one more thing, ajax request execute on page load i think OP needs when form submit i think....

Comment: I've done with var searchTerm = "<?php echo $x; ?>"; like this $x = $_POST['search']; Then I fix this data:"actionfunction=showData&page=1search="+searchTerm and I get data from searchTerm to searchby.php like $searchstring = $data['seacrh']; but it does not work.

Comment: not clear, r u getting data in this $_POST['search'] ???

Comment: @devpro i'm not sure what behavior he try to reach.

Comment: i think u r talking about you are getting post data in php file that u send from the ajax, right, but still not work ?? plz correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: @devpro Yes, Can we talk in chat room?

Comment: yes you can ..............

Comment: @devpro For an example : When I input 'Shirt' and press button to search my `$_POST['seacrh']` is getting 'Shirt' But I don't know how to send `$_POST['search']` to searchby.php

Comment: Are u sure?? Your form gets submitted. I did't see the form submission from your code

Comment: yes OP didnt submit as per ajax, looking for yur code.. as i told u about the submission.

Comment: @Jagadeesh Yes, I've check with echo $_POST['search']; in my search.php and it gets data. But in my searchby.php it does not gets any data.

Comment: @devpro Okay, I'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send search value in ajax param as:

```
var searchVal = $("#search").val(); // get value of search box
$.ajax({
    url:"searchby.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:"search="+searchVal+"&actionfunction=showData&page=1",
    cache: false,
    success: function(response){
        $('#loading').hide();
        $('#demoajax').html(response);
    }
});
```

---

**UPDATE 1:**

Send ajax request when form submit, you can follow this example:

```
$(".btn").click(function(){

var searchVal = $("#search").val(); // get value of search box
$.ajax({
    url:"searchby.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:"search="+searchVal+"&actionfunction=showData&page=1",
    cache: false,
    success: function(response){
        $('#loading').hide();
        $('#demoajax').html(response);
    }
});

});
```

**In PHP (searchby.php) debug what are you getting in $_POST:**

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: I've tried your code but my infinite scroll it's not working.

Comment: I've get infinite scroll from this [Demo](http://www.infotuts.com/ajax-infinite-scroll-using-jquery-php-mysql/).

Comment: @VintageBeef: first of all check your ajax request on form submission is it working or not... and move on scrolling code, so disable scrolling code.

Comment: @VintageBeef: or do the same for scroll ajax code.. var searchVal = $("#search").val(); // get value of search box

Comment: My infinite scroll display by 3 items of 6 items when I search it does not display all of my data. :(

Comment: @VintageBeef: happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the input `search` value in your post request, to retrieve this value you could use id selector `#`, e.g :

```
var search = $('#search').val();

$.ajax({
    url:"searchby.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:"actionfunction=showData&page=1&search="+search,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response){
        $('#loading').hide();
        $('#demoajax').html(response);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this before but my infinite scroll will get all of my data not  only word that I've input.